# Fastest way to accumulate weighted counts from multiple collections.Counter Objects?

Tags: python, performance, counter, weighted, cumulative-sum

I want to merge multiple `collections.Counter` objects, where the counts are weighted with a floating point factor before they are added (see code). Each counter object has about 5000 keys and most (but not all) of the keys are shared among all counter objects.

My current code is extremely slow. I use it to merge about 4000 counter objects by merging them in sequence using the following function:

```
def addCounters(c1, c2, factor = 1.0):
    merged = c1
    for word, count in c2.iteritems():
        if word in merged:
            merged[word] = float(merged[word]) + float(count) * factor
        else:
            merged[word] = float(count) * factor
    return merged
```

According to my `cProfile` measurements 4181 calls will run in unacceptably slow 25 seconds. This is very annoying since it also freezes my GUI.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
4181    1.056    0.000   25.088    0.006   MyClass.py:30(addCounters)
```

Does anyone know of a much faster way to do this?

Comment: This is not going to be much faster, but you could eliminate your `if` statement: since Counter objects return `0` for missing items, instead of `KeyError`, you can use `merged[word] = float(merged[word]) + float(count) * factor`, even if `word` is not in `merged`. It's only an O(1) call, so I don't expect much of a performance improvement.

Comment: Are you always using the same weight for all the counters? If so, you could use the `+` operator to merge the counts, then scale the final result with an iteration. If not, could you scale the values going into the counters so that you don't need to weight them when you're merging?

Comment: Why do need all these `float() ` conversions? The multiplication with `factor` should be enough. Won't make it faster though.

Comment: I'm not sure any processing you can do on 20 million items is going to be very fast (e.g. fast enough for a GUI to still be interactive). You may want to kick this work out to a thread or something, so you don't need to care exactly how long it takes.

Comment: The float cast was just out of habit, yes, it should be done outside the loop to give some possibly small perf. improvement. The reason behind not using the advantage that Counter returns 0 if key is not present was because I historically used this code for dict objects before I switched to counters. My weights are generally different. If they are the same I already optimized with a+b before but it was even slower. Thread would fix freezing but usr would still need to wait the same time until GUI is updated. Precalculating is not possible, because input can't be predicted until button pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially inspired by Mr. F I came up with something, which runs for 4.3 seconds on my local computer. I'd still be very happy if someone can make it even faster. My approach works with both, `dict` and `collections.Counter`

Basically, I "export" the keys into sets and then divide them into 3 groups:

1. keys unique to `c1`
2. keys unique to `c2`
3. keys occuring in both.

   - The counts from group 1 are already final since we do c1+factor*c2 and there is no count in c2
   - Counts from group 2 only need to be multiplied with the factor since there is no count in c1
   - Now, keys in group 3 are guaranteed to exist in both `c1` and `c2`, their counts can be calculated easily again
   - Finally everything is merged together

def addCounters(c1, c2, factor = 1.0):

```
#make sure factor is float
factor = float(factor)
#get keys as sets 
c1keys, c2keys = set(c1.keys()), set(c2.keys())
#keys only in c1
c1only = c1keys.difference(c2keys)
#keys only in c2
c2only = c1keys.difference(c1keys)
#keys guaranteed in both
both = c1keys.intersection(c2keys)

#generate dicts for keys which are unique to c1 or c2
c1onlydict = dict((w,c1[w]) for w in c1only)
c2onlydict = dict((w,c2[w]*factor) for w in c2only)
#merge
loners = dict(c1onlydict, **c2onlydict)

#now create the directory with keys which exist in both
bothdict = dict((key, c1[key] + c2[key]*factor) for key in both)

#merge everything
return dict(loners, **bothdict)
```

I believe that the main reason why it runs faster is that when adding multiple counters/dicts one will always feed the previous cumulation back to the method as `c1`. Therefore `c1onlydict` (which is easiest to create and will probably have highly optimized bytecode) will become huge in size while `c2onlydict` and `bothdict` will be tiny by comparison.

Answer (score 4):

A few things that may help:

1. Don't constantly wrap in `float` calls if you're just trying to force `int` to `float`; Python will convert for you as it does the math as long as you guarantee `factor` is `float`
2. If your `Counter` objects aren't using `Counter` specific features, converting to `dict` or `defaultdict(int)` (or `defaultdict(float)` for this function) may help; `dict` and `defaultdict` are (in the CPython reference interpreter) implemented in C, where `Counter` is implemented in Python, which adds overhead to all uses. In local testing (on Python 3.5 admittedly, which may not match 2.7 performance precisely), using your original code and doing nothing but using `defaultdict(int)` for inputs and outputs reduced runtime on a similar set of inputs from ~19 seconds to ~12 seconds.
3. Probably not meaningful, but avoiding two separate explicit lookups by using `x[k] += y * z` over `x[k] = x[k] + y * z` may (mildly) improve speed (two lookups actually happen thanks to the way `+=` is implemented, but the byte code is slightly more efficient)
4. Don't check for the existence of each `word` in `merged` since `Counter` handles this for you by returning `0` whether or not the key exists (and `defaultdict(int)` or `defaultdict(float)` would create it for you)

Ignoring the change of types from `Counter` to something else for the inputs, the improved code would look like:

```
def addCounters(c1, c2, factor=1.0):
    # Assume inputs are defaultdict(int), not Counter
    merged = c1
    factor = float(factor)  # In case someone passes non-float default
    for word, count in c2.iteritems():
        merged[word] += count * factor
    return merged
```

In local tests on Python 3.5 (only code difference is using `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()`), between using `defaultdict(int)` and making these code changes, in a dataset similar to the one you describe, the total time drops from ~19 seconds to ~5.5 seconds. Probably still too long to be acceptable in a GUI event loop, but it's going to be hard to improve on that.

Comment: Sounds like you may be onto something. However I use python 2.7.6. Will check if items() already exists there. Will also perform new measurements with your code.

Comment: @evolution: Don't worry about `items` vs. `iteritems`. On Py2, use `iteritems`, on Py3, `items`. I just was mentioning using `items` because I was on 3.5 (where `items` is the same as 2.7's `viewitems`, and performance-wise equivalent to `itemitems` when used for iteration).

Comment: In my own benchmarks, this is about 5x faster than the OP's code.

Comment: In all my measurements so far only using dict instead of Counter brings the time down from 25 to 18 s.

Comment: @evolution: That seems about right; my tests used `int`s as keys (so hashing was cheap), where each `Counter` was built using 5000 keys from a set of 6000 possibles. Shared keys were equal by identity, not value, so many comparisons were just pointer checks, not value comparisons (and the value comparisons were still cheap). That's all roughly fixed overhead on top of the "base cost"; we both saved about 7 seconds by using containers with lower overhead, which makes some sense. Variations between 2.7 and 3.5 could also explain some of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mobile so I can't profile, but the implementation below appears to have much simplified disassembled byte code than the original. Might be worth a try if a plain dict is ok.

```
def addCounters(c1, c2, factor=1.0):
    return dict(c1, **{w:(c1[w] + c*factor) for w,c in c2.iteritems()})
```

If you need to support plain `dict` arguments as well (instead of solely `Counter` which implicitly behaves like a `defaultdict` so that `c1[w]` is always safe), you can perform `c1.get(w, 0)`.

```
def addCounters(c1, c2, factor=1.0):
    return dict(c1, **{w:(c1.get(w, 0) + c*factor) for w,c in c2.iteritems()})
```

Comment: That won't include the values originally in `c1` unless they also appear in `c2`. Also, it's returning a `set`, not a `dict`; the keys are discarded.

Comment: Looks like a very nice one liner, but doesn't work. I will experiment if I can fix it.

Comment: One-liner-ness rarely matters. The point here is to use only fast C-layer dict operations, while also avoiding SETUP_LOOP stuff.

Comment: Your new correction makes an output that looks good until there is a word w which is in c2 but not in c1 in which case it gives a KeyError. I'll still do some experimenting what happens if I artificially exclude those cases.

Comment: If you are using a `Counter` for `c1` then this would not happen, as `Counter` will act like a `defaultdict` automatically and provide a value of 0 for items not found (in fact, that was the entire point of writing it as a dict comprehension in my view) -- so you must be not using `Counter` as you claimed. You can replace the part `c1[w]` with `c1.get(w, 0)` if you need this extra compatibility.

Comment: You are right. I also used your idea to come up with this, which runs in 5 seconds on dicts:    
`def addCounters(c1, c2, factor = 1.0):
factor = float(factor)
c1keys, c2keys = set(c1.keys()), set(c2.keys())
c1only = c1keys.difference(c2keys)
c2only = c1keys.difference(c1keys)
both = c1keys.intersection(c2keys)
c1onlydict = dict((w,c) for w,c in c1.iteritems() if w in c1only)
c2onlydict = dict((w,c*factor) for w,c in c2.iteritems() if w in c2only)
loners = dict(c1onlydict, **c2onlydict)
bothdict = dict((key, c1[key] + c2[key]*factor) for key in both)
        return dict(loners, **bothdict)`

Comment: @evolution: FYI, you can probably save some work there by changing `set(c1.keys())` to `c1.viewkeys()` (and same for `c2`). `KeysView`s are set-like already (you can use `&`, `|`, etc. with them), and they'll save you one round of object construction.

Comment: Hm... It raises to 47 seconds when using viewkeys(), I used the "-" operator for difference() and "&" operator for intersection(). I think there may be some unwanted iteration in the background which doesn't happen with a set.